# Generating an image from pre-existing ones?

Tags: php, image

This is kinda confusing, so forgive me if you don't understand what I am asking. I'm trying to develop my skills and I wanted to move onto images as a next step. I did a bit of searching and I thought a good way to try this would maybe be to generate military ribbon racks depending on the options the user selects.

(See something like this as an example: http://www.ribbon-rack-builder.com/ribbons/build/4)

Now, from looking at the source code I can see that the creator of that website creates a form with all of the different ribbons and allows the user to select the ones they want with checkboxes. This form is then posted to some PHP on the page somewhere.

Being new to the image concept I have no idea what kind of PHP this would be. Could anyone give me an idea of how this website could do this and where I should start should I want to create something similar?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597227/php-add-a-picture-onto-another

Comment: [GD and Image Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

Comment: @user2547576 Did my answer answer your question? If so, please mark it as "Answered." If not, please let me know how else I can help.

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need to [get which checkboxes were checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997271/761793):

> Set the name in the form to check_list[] and you will be able to
>   access all the checkboxes as an array($_POST['check_list'][])

Second, you'll most likely want to use the [GD and Image Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) built into PHP.

There is a lot there, and it can be confusing, so I suggest you do some reading through questions on SO on the subject: [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=merge+image+[php]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=merge%20image%20%5Bphp%5D)