# How do you replace a section of an image with another image?

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm looking for a way to insert an image in place of a green-screen screen spot on an image.

I have manually edited the result i'm looking for, but, i don't know how to do this in PHP.

Are there any API's/Services or examples anyone could share with me?

[image]

Comment: Have you googled this? I did "php insert image in another" and found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597227/php-add-a-picture-onto-another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php add a picture onto another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597227/php-add-a-picture-onto-another)

Comment: Please provide the image of the yellow digger-thing.